# Sql query to find subset of a given table

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, subset

Given this table:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_func_sum

How will I generate list of OrderIds where sum of quantity is at most 90. How do I express the same in SQL ? There can be multiple answers for the same query. How will you generate them all? In one way, this also looks like knapsack problem to me, but I dunno how to express the same in SQL.

You will probably need to execute the query

```
SELECT * FROM OrderDetails;
```

in the web page

Comment: You should add the data from the link to the question. Links then break and the question is useless for future visitors.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to generate *all* possible solutions with just SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in Postgres with a recursive CTE, but it will be massively inefficient:

```
With Recursive search_orders(maxid, quantity, used) AS (
    Select
        od.OrderDetailsID,
        od.quantity,
        array[od.OrderDetailsID]
    from
        OrderDetails od
    Where
        quantity < 90
    Union All
    Select
        od.OrderDetailsID,
        sod.quantity + od.quantity,
        used || od.OrderDetailsID
    From
        OrderDetails od,
        search_orders sod
    Where
        od.OrderDetailsID > sod.maxid and
        od.quantity < 90 - sod.quantity
)
Select
    used,
    quantity
From
    search_orders sod
Where
    not exists (
        select 'x'
    from
        OrderDetails od
    Where
        Not od.OrderDetailsID = Any(used) and
        od.quantity < 90 - sod.quantity
    )
```

If you want all combinations, regardless of whether you could add another item without going over the quantity limit, you can remove the last where clause

**<kbd>[Example SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/10191/4)</kbd>**

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT OrderID, SUM(Quantity) AS TotalItemsOrdered 
FROM OrderDetails
GROUP BY OrderID
HAVING SUM(Quantity)<= 90
```

Comment: It seems the OP wants a `list of OrderIds where sum of quantity is at most 90`. Based on the *knapsack* reference in the question indeed wants a list of order ids. Weird request

Comment: that query will return  each orderid whos quantity <= 90 . I need a list of orderid where total sum of quantity in that list is <= 90.

Comment: Isn't that what the above query does?  The above query show 151 OrderIDs that have a total sum of quantity that is less than 90.